# Playing video in iPhone simulator with Media Player Framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, media-player

I am giving my entire code below if that helps anyway.....

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "MediaPlayerViewController.h"
#import "TwitterViewController.h"
#import "YoutubeViewController.h"

@implementation ContentViewController

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize imageView1;
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize toolBar;
@synthesize item;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - XMLParser Delegate

-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL{

NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[rssParser parse];
NSLog(@"Parsed");
}

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

NSLog(@"Found file and started parsing");
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{

NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download feed from website (Error Code %i)",  [parseError code]];
NSLog(@"Error parsing xml: %@", errorString);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

  currentElement = [elementName copy];
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {

    rssElement      = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    title           = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    link            = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    description     = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    copyright       = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
  } 
}


-(void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {

    [rssElement setObject:title                 forKey:@"title"];
    [rssElement setObject:link                  forKey:@"link"];
    [rssElement setObject:description           forKey:@"description"];
    [rssElement setObject:copyright             forKey:@"copyright"];

    [item addObject:[rssElement copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding stories %@", title);
  }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

  if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:string];
  }else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:string];
  }else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
    [description appendString:string];
  }else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"copyright"]) {
    [copyright appendString:string];
  }
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

NSLog(@"all done");
NSLog(@"item array has %d items", [item count]);
[tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"Finished Parsing");
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

/* Add Segmented Controller */

if (segmentedControl == nil) {
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Video", @"Images", @"Audio", nil]];
}


[segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(55.0, 47.0, 180.0, 31.0)];
[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[segmentedControl setWidth:70.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segmentedControl setWidth:70.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[segmentedControl setWidth:70.0 forSegmentAtIndex:2];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(segmentClick:) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];

//    [[[segmentedControl subviews]objectAtIndex:0]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

/* Add Image View */

imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Harry.png"];

/* Add Page Control */

pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 250.0, 100.0 ,10.0);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;

[self.view addSubview:pageControl];

/* Customize Table View */

tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackground.png"];

item = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if ([item count] == 0) {

    path = @"http://172.19.58.172/Android/GetApprovedList.php?ip=172.19.58.172&type=Video";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Returned %@", item);
}

headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 270.0, 300.0, 14.0)];
headerLabel.text = @"Latest Videos";
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:headerLabel];
}

/* Assign control to Segment Controller */

-(void)segmentClick:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentControl {

if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){


    if ([item count] == 0) {

        path = @"http://172.19.58.172/Android/GetApprovedList.php?ip=172.19.58.172&type=Image";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        [tableView reloadData];
        headerLabel.text = @"Latest Images";
        NSLog(@"Returned %@",item);
    }
}
else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
    if ([item count] == 0) {

        path = @"http://172.19.58.172/Android/GetApprovedList.php?ip=172.19.58.172&type=Audio";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        [tableView reloadData];
        headerLabel.text = @"Latest Audios";
        NSLog(@"Returned no items");
        //            [[[segmentedControl subviews]objectAtIndex:2]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
else {
    if ([item count] == 0) {

        path = @"http://172.19.58.172/Android/GetApprovedList.php?ip=172.19.58.172&type=Video";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        [tableView reloadData];
        headerLabel.text = @"Latest Videos";
        NSLog(@"Returned %@", item);
    }        
    //        [[[segmentedControl subviews]objectAtIndex:0]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  }
}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSLog(@"this is returned %@", item);
return item.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

int feed = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
cell.textLabel.text = [[item objectAtIndex:feed]objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[item objectAtIndex:feed]objectForKey:@"description"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *moviePath = [self.item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
NSLog(@"Item has %@", movieURL);
playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[playerController play];

//    MediaPlayerViewController *mediaView = [[MediaPlayerViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"MediaPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
//    [self presentModalViewController:mediaView animated:YES];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    shareAlert = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share to" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"     
 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Facebook" otherButtonTitles:@"Twitter", nil];
    [shareAlert showInView:self.view];
  }
  else if (buttonIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"button 2");
  }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    TwitterViewController *twitterController = [[TwitterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TwitterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:twitterController animated:YES];

  }
}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification{
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[moviePlayerController release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Changed didSelectRow method like following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

moviePath = [[item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"link"];
NSLog(@"moviepath has %@", moviePath);
movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
NSLog(@"movieURL has %@", movieURL);
viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:viewController];

viewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[playerController play];
viewController = nil; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:viewController];

}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

viewController = [notification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:viewController];

if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}

}
```

Now, on selecting any row a blank screen is coming and the application gets stuck there. Video is not played

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found out the problem with videos.....The names of the videos parsed from php is incorrect....Thanks all for their help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at you code what i can tell you is that you dont have to reallocate your item object.

If you have allocated your `item` object somewhere in the class and stored the values in it then do not reallocate it again as you did here:

```
item = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *moviePath = [item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

by reallocating it you are allocating a new memory to it and in the new memory there is no objects present.

Comment: I do have the same problem even if don't put that line for reallocating

Comment: have you allocated that `item` object anywhere in the class or you are doing it in that function only

Comment: no.......i have used it in different methods and so have allocated it earlier....if you need the entire code i can post it....but it's too long

Comment: you can do one thing that allocate that `item` in didLoad function then use it where ever you want. dont forget use the getter and setter for that. now you can do like `NSString *moviePath = [self.item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Thanks...that removed the error but now geeting SIGABRT in the next line that is:   NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
Please let me what is that i am doing wrong in allocating my objects....

Comment: First do `NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);` This will tell you what you are actually getting in that object and try instead of writing `NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];` try `NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];` hope that will work

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",moviePath); is giving me the content of the cell i am selecting....but on the whole same problem even with NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];

Comment: content of the cell??? it should be giving you the URL of the video to you...recheck your code..

Comment: it gives the url of the video

Answer (score 0):

you are allocating new memory to your array by : `item = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` . It means `NO` objects in it right now. And you are trying to access it by `NSString *moviePath = [item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` where there is NO object at `indexPath.row` thats why it crashed.

Comment: Well, i am facing the same problem even if i am not allocating the array there...

Comment: @DipanjanDutta: It simply means array out of bound !

Answer (score 0):

There was actually nothing wrong with the code for playing video. The error was in the code for parsing and retrieving the rss feed which eventually was giving me wrong names of the videos. hence, videos were not playing.

The parsing code is [Parsing attributes with same name but in different fields in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108223/parsing-attributes-with-same-name-but-in-different-fields-in-ios)